# Passing List from Controller to View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

// Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var People = new List<Customer>
      {
      new Customer { Name = "Customer 1" },
      new Customer { Name = "Customer 2"}


       };
        return View(People); 

    }
```

// VIEW

```
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

@foreach (var item in People)

```
<p>@item</p>
```

//I'm confused with View. I have tried all different options, including Youtube and stack overflow, and it seems like it's not working.

Comment: Your current action method code is passing the list to the view. What is your confusion. Your view code should have `@model List<Customer>` if you do not already have.

Comment: `foreach(string item in Model)` implies you passed a `List<string>` instead of `List<Customer>`.

Comment: @Shyju - did not work.

Comment: @Jasen I'm putting List<Customer> thats what i need to put not List <String>

Comment: Then change your loop `foreach (var item in Model)`

Comment: @Jasen still doesnt work, this is what im getting:
Line 31:     public class _Page_Views_Customers_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<List <Customer>> {

Comment: "doesn't work" does not help us help you. Provide a minimal, viable, and complete example so we can replicate the problem. Show us the error you are getting and what result you expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to show your data with this code

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var people = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer{Name = "kamasdfsaol"},
            new Customer{Name = "susuasdfsa"}
        };
        return View(people);
    }
```

and your view should look like this

```
 @model IEnumerable<Customer>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
     @item.Name <br/>
 }
```